# Effective way to down sample or up sample signals without losing information?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-imputation, signal-processing, interpolation

I have an edf data here that I got from this [website](https://www.scidb.cn/en/detail?dataSetId=778740145531650048). The data was supposed to be fed into an ML model. The data is taken from a sleep study (polysomnography). However, the data for some of the signals were sampled with different frequencies as is described in this table:

[image: Basic properties of the channels included in the EDF fles of the dataset.]

So for the signals that were sampled with 200HZ has about 72000 data points, whereas the snore signal sampled at 500 HZ has 1800000 data points. Obviously, I can't create a dataframe just from these values because the columns would not be of the same length. Is it better to down sample or up sample some of these data to achieve a features of the same length? If so, what's the best reference? To down sample it to least sampling frequency used or to up sample the data to the highest sampling frequency used? I understand that most ML models can't accept input features that are not of similar lengths with other input features and that is my main concern. The only channels I'm working with are one of the EEG channels, ECG, pulse rate, SpO2, and the 2 Flow Patient (pressure and thermistor) channels

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems more like a missing data problem to me.  At 00:01.000 (i.e., exactly the first second mark) you will have data on all variables, at 00:01.002 you will the next reading for the 500Hz channels, at 01:00.005 you will have values for the 200Hz channels.  What do you do with the missing data - only take the values measured at exactly the second (impose a 1Hz rate across the board)? Replicate previous values until the new one?  Impute (perhaps with time-trends)?  Thinking about it as a missing data problem may be more fruitful.

Comment: Well instead of trying to fill in data is it possible to make the features have a list of values instead of single numerical values? Like for the 200Hz features, is it possible for their data points to simply have a list of 6000 numerical values in a list?

Comment: Sure, but most statistical routines are looking for a rectangular dataset with one entry per cell.  And, filling in the data, say with the most recent previous measurement would essentially be the same as associating a single 1Hz measurement with a list of 200, 200Hz measurements.